# how to configure intellij Idea\pyCharm reformating HTML code(one line for only one element)

Tags: html, intellij-idea, pycharm, reformat

i want to get code like this:

```
<div>
    <span> 
        <a>
            text
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

from this:

```
<div><span><a>text</a></span></div>
```